# "Furthermore, I believe our salary should be abolished"

Tags: classical-latin, cato

What is the Latin for the above phrase?

For background - I am a small-town local politician and have been campaigning for some time to abolish the small salary, or "allowance", which is paid to members of the council I sit on.  The council has little money, and we all have paid day jobs in the local community, mostly as professional people or successful business owners.

I would like to begin ending each of my speeches to the council with the above phrase, as a reference to Cato the Elder and "Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam".  I would be grateful for a correct Latin translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In imitation of Cato's famous saying:

> *Ceterum censeo salaria nostra abroganda esse.*
>   'Furthermore, I think that our salaries should be abolished.'

Cato's saying is often paraphrased as *Carthago delenda est,* but he himself said *ceterum censeo Carthaginem delendam esse*. It's a matter of direct vs. indirect speech.

Answer (score 0):

What about

> Ceterum, credo stipendio nostro debere removeri

I think it has the advantage that, from a Spanish speaker perspective, this is (more or less) perfectly understandable (`creo [que el] estipendio nuestro debe [ser] removido`).

Comment: This looks a little ungrammatical to me. I would either use *debere* instead of *debet* (as an ACI, the accusative being *removeri*) or add *ut* between the first two words and separate the parenthetical *ut credo* with commas from both sides. Perhaps a conjunction like *quod* after *credo* could also work, but then I'd be inclined to change *debet* to conjunctive.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Much to learn yet. :)

Comment: So have we all, and that's why we're here. :)